# How to mock an object/function inside a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am having trouble mocking a function inside a module. (Not sure if this is possible.

So I have a module called myActions.ts

```
import * as Config from "../utils/Config";
const _config = Config.getConfig();

export const requestLoadDataA = (postLoadAction: Function = undefined) => {
    return async function (dispatch, getState) {

        const client = { url: `${_config.ApiUrl}getDataA` };

        ...
    }
}
```

This module contains a Config.getConfig() and this is what I want to mock.

Config module looks like this:

```
export  const getConfig = () => {
    const app = document.getElementById("react-app");
    if (app) {
        const config = app.dataset.configuration;
        return JSON.parse(config) as IConfiguration;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }

};
```

This is the jest test I have so far and it doesn't work:

```
describe("DATA_A Action Creator (Sync): Tests", () => {
    afterEach(fetchMock.restore);

    it("REQUEST and SUCCESS actions on successful loadData()", () => {
        const dataA: any = require("../../__mockData__/dataA.json");         

        fetchMock.mock("/getDataA", {
            status: 200,
            body: dataA
        });



        const _config = { };
        const spy = jest.spyOn(Config, "getConfig");
        spy.mockReturnValue(_config);


        const store = mockStore({ 
            dataA: { 
                hasLoadedEntities: false,  
                isLoadingEntities: false
            }
        });

        return store.dispatch(aActions.requestLoadDataA())
            .then(() => {
                const expectedActions = store.getActions();
                expect(expectedActions.length).toEqual(2);
                expect(expectedActions).toContainEqual({ type: ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_A_REQUESTED });
                expect(expectedActions).toContainEqual({ type: ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_A_SUCCESS, data: resultData });
            });
    });
}
```

I get a "cannot read property 'ApiUrl' of undefined.
How can I mock the _config.ApiUrl object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you.

you can mock your default import like this

```
import * as Config from "../utils/Config";


jest.mock("../utils/Config", () => ({
      getConfig: () => ({ ApiUrl: 'yourMockApiUrl' })
}));
```

Comment: I added your code to the jest test before the requestLoadDataA() but it doesn't work, _config  is still undefined. Any idea?

Comment: can you try with [mockImplementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

Comment: The path is correct, if I change it I get the message "Cannot find module....". The mockImplementation has the same result. I think this is because the Config module is not a typescript class, in only has some functions that are exported, then in the tests file I am importing everything * as Config and I don't know to implement the mock correctly for this scenario

Comment: Just thinking, how can I make sure that "const _config = Config.getConfig();" is called in the myActions.ts before I call the requestLoadDataA()?

Comment: oh, I just made it. I should be mocking the _config in myActions.ts. Your solution helped me.